# website html checker wc3validator but fatal error showing

Tags: class, validation

when i have search my website url in [wc3validator](https://validator.w3.org) and last error showing

> Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will
>   be ignored.

```
pt></head><body↩class="test-class cms-index-index cms-home"> <scri
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bug. They should fix it.

Comment: but how can fix that?

Comment: Cannot fix it, because there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: but error showing in w3validator

Comment: Start from first comment ;)